# Can i get any service provider for voice call from mobile?

Tags: android, call, voip, skype

I am developing a application like VOIP.

One feature of application is calls within the application just like (Viber). 
Another one calls to mobile numbers and landlines like skype calling.

For calls from application to application i got SIP, but i did not get any service for calling to other mobile numbers.

Do you have any known service providers to make calls to mobiles and landlines.

Please share your ideas and Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Only mad people who thinks that he knows everything, will give negative votes and tries to close the question.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html see this link